# Deleting a row in a Subform

Tags: ms-access

I have a Subform within a Form in Access 03. I need a macro that will delete a row in the subform. I tried the below code but it only deletes the fields in the form.

```
Private Sub Command104_Click()    
On Error GoTo Err_cmdDeleteCustomer_Click

DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acEditMenu, 8, , acMenuVer70
DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acEditMenu, 6, , acMenuVer70

Exit_cmdDeleteCustomer_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_cmdDeleteCustomer_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_cmdDeleteCustomer_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Wizard code. It is very bad and has been deprecated for sometime. The newer version is DoCmd.RunCommand. For the subform, it would be easier to run a little sql from a command button, for example:

```
 Dim db As Database
 Dim sSQL As String

 Set db = CurrentDB
 sSQL = "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID =" & Me.MyNumericIDControlName
 db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

 MsgBox "Deleted " & db.RecordsAffected
```

Comment: Me.MyNumericIDControlName should be replaced with what??

Comment: You'll want to requery the subform after the delete.